# Unable to enlarge a cloned partition

Tags: partitioning

Please help, I have cloned my 1T ssd onto a 2T ssd. There were 2 existing partitions a boot and ext4 the ext4 is 0.953G in size.

I am only able to communicate with my pi4 through ssh command line.
In cfdisk i can see the free space.

I recently tried the following.
1st - cfdisk and select partition to enlarge and denied due to max size 0.999 t

2nd - enlarge using a windows and lazesoft however changing format is the only way and wipes the data.

3rd - I tried Gparted i did write to disk (y) now the UUID is different i still cant enlarge the partition and, i don't know what to do?

before gparted (sudo gdisk /dev/sda)

/dev/sda1: LABEL_FATBOOT="boot" LABEL="boot" UUID="6ED3-22D6" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="4eb29ce2-01"

/dev/sda2: LABEL="rootfs" UUID="e603363f-79c3-421f-a49e-3c01c0a6dd23" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="4eb29ce2-02"

**AFTER GPARTED**

/dev/sda1: LABEL="boot" UUID="7F5B-B190" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="Microsoft basic data" PARTUUID="9eb99f7c-b44d-4666-a05a-08be5c380e0e"

/dev/sda2: LABEL="rootfs" UUID="e603363f-79c3-421f-a49e-3c01c0a6dd23" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Linux filesystem" PARTUUID="f51ead30-9a47-41ac-add5-f9498309abd0"

**cmnd~  sudo fdisk /dev/sda  print**

Disk /dev/sda: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: PSSD T7
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: CE59ACB3-9BBC-4A29-804E-E01FADDF9B56

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048    1222655    1220608   596M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda2  1954035712 3907028399 1952992688 931.3G Linux filesystem

**Then i used cmnd~ sudo resize2fs /dev/sda2 +953G**

resize2fs 1.46.2 (28-Feb-2021)
The containing partition (or device) is only 244124086 (4k) blocks.
You requested a new size of 249823232 blocks.

I really dont know what to do now, any ideas? ps, im a novice at ubuntu commands.

Comment: Resize2fs without a size should fill the partition. I thought gparyef would/could do that automatically.

Comment: i get the same msg without the size specified. i will look at gparyef now.

Comment: I did use gparted not sure what ive done wrong?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. How did you try a Windows tool and GParted if you can only access the disk via ssh? I assume you plugged it in to a different computer. The error you got from resize2fs tells you what you did wrong. You tried to add more space than is available. Where did 953 come from? You have probably confused GB and GiB. GParted will not work if you are trying to resize a running root partition. @ubfan1 comment may well be your solution.